# Error when installing asterisk

Tags: asterisk

when trying to install asterisk i get this error:

```
[root@localhost asterisk-15.4.0]# make install
CC="cc" CXX="g++" LD="" AR="" RANLIB="" CFLAGS="" LDFLAGS="" make -C menuselect CONFIGURE_SILENT="--silent" makeopts
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/asterisk/asterisk-15.4.0/menuselect'
make[1]: `makeopts' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/asterisk/asterisk-15.4.0/menuselect'
   [LD] chan_unistim.o -> chan_unistim.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtbeginT.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against hidden symbol `__TMC_END__' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [chan_unistim.so] Error 1
make: *** [channels] Error 2
[root@localhost asterisk-15.4.0]#
```

Comment: Simplest way for you is disable chan_unistrim using **make menuconfig**. No way say what is not ok in your environment.